# Avoid prop drilling in mapped components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im mapping over some data and returning a `NestedComponentOne` each time. A nested child component `NestedComponentThree` needs access to a `restaurant`. How can I avoid prop drilling here? Wrapping every `NestedComponentOne` in a provider seems wrong.

```js
const DATA = ["Restaurant 1"," Resto 2", "resto 3"]

export default DATA
```

```js
import data from './data'


export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map((restaurant) => {
        return <NestedComponentOne/>
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

const NestedComponentOne = () => <div><NestedComponentTwo/></div>
const NestedComponentTwo = () => <div><NestedComponentThree/></div>
// I need access to restaurant
const NestedComponentThree = () => <div>restaurant</div>
```

Comment: Wrapping every `NestedComponentOne` in a provider seems perfectly fine to me.

Comment: you can also use context or redux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The React doc recommends [component composition](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#:%7E:text=If%20you%20only%20want%20to,a%20simpler%20solution%20than%20context.&text=It%20might%20feel%20redundant%20to,Avatar%20component%20really%20needs%20it.):

> Context is primarily used when some data needs to be accessible by **many** components at different nesting levels. Apply it sparingly because it makes component reuse more difficult.
>
> If you only want to avoid passing some props through many levels, component composition is often a simpler solution than context.

So, you could for example do the following:

```
const data = ['Restaurant 1', ' Resto 2', 'resto 3'];
export default function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            {data.map((restaurant) => {
                return (
                    <NestedComponentOne>
                        <NestedComponentTwo>
                            <NestedComponentThree restaurant={restaurant} />
                        </NestedComponentTwo>
                    </NestedComponentOne>
                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
}

const NestedComponentOne = ({ children }) => <div>{children}</div>;
const NestedComponentTwo = ({ children }) => <div>{children}</div>;
// Now you have access in this component to restaurant
const NestedComponentThree = ({ restaurant }) => <div>{restaurant}</div>;
```

Another way to do this is by passing the component as a prop:

```
const data = ['Restaurant 1', ' Resto 2', 'resto 3'];
export default function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            {data.map((restaurant) => {
                return (
                    <NestedComponentOne
                        componentTwo={
                            <NestedComponentTwo
                                componentThree={
                                    <NestedComponentThree restaurant={restaurant} />
                                }
                            />
                        }
                    />
                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
}

const NestedComponentOne = ({ componentTwo }) => <div>{componentTwo}</div>;
const NestedComponentTwo = ({ componentThree }) => <div>{componentThree}</div>;
// Now you have access in this component to restaurant
const NestedComponentThree = ({ restaurant }) => <div>{restaurant}</div>;
```